# Trouble With Regex and Velocity

Tags: regex, velocity, dotcms

I just started using dotCMS for work to modify the existing website. I am trying to create a widget that takes a custom structure field called urlTitle. It takes the Title of an event and makes it url friendly. [Here is a tutorial describing the urlTitle](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EUMC4j-APZU)

I have a regex that is written fine for javascript. My problem is when I try to use the same regex in velocity, I am getting some troubles.

Here is the javascript from the tutorial:

```
<script>
    function updateDisplayURLTitle(){

        // get the title entered by the user
        var plainTitle = dojo.byId("title");    

        // make a friendly url
        var urlTitle = plainTitle.value.toLowerCase();
        urlTitle= urlTitle.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
        urlTitle = urlTitle.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/g,' '); 
        urlTitle = urlTitle.replace(/\s/g, "-");
        while(urlTitle.indexOf("--") > -1){
            urlTitle = urlTitle.replace("--",'-');  
        }

        // set the values of the display place holder and the custom field
        // the   is to hold the div open
        dojo.byId("displayURLTitle").innerHTML = urlTitle;
        dojo.byId("urlTitle").value=urlTitle;
    }

    // attach this the text1 field onchange
    dojo.connect(dojo.byId("title"), "onchange", null, "updateDisplayURLTitle");

    // populate the field on load
    dojo.addOnLoad(updateDisplayURLTitle);

</script>
<div id="displayURLTitle" style="height:20px"> </div>
```

Then here is my velocity code for my widget:

```
#set($nowsers = $date.format('yyyyMMddHHmmss', $date.getDate()))
#set($con = $dotcontent.pull("+structureName:calendarEvent +(conhost:48190c8c-42c4-46af-8d1a-0cd5db894797 conhost:SYSTEM_HOST) +calendarEvent.startDate:[$nowsers TO 21001010101000]",1,"calendarEvent.startDate"))
    <ul>
    #foreach($event in $con)
        <li>
           <a href="events/$event.urlTitle?id=$event.identifier">$event.title</a>
            <p> $event.description</p>
        </li>

#set($temp = $event.title.toLowerCase())
#set($temp = $temp.replaceAll('/^\s+|\s+$/g', ""))
#set($temp = $temp.replaceAll('/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/g', " "))
#set($temp = $temp.replaceAll('/\s/g', "-"))
$temp


$temp
#end
```

My goal is to have the regex from the javascript work with the velocity. Right now it doesn't work and I'm not that skilled with regex, so far my research has lead me nowhere.

Another thing I cant figure out is what the `/g` does. I can't find it in any regex resource website.

Comment: /g aka Global ,mean do not stop the regex operation eventhough it found the match..layman term, multiple search

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It turns out that the escape characer / in front of the regex patter, and the /g were causing the pattern to fail so it must not be needed for the method used in velocity.